# Debugging vtable Linker Errors in GCC

Tags: debugging, gcc, linker, vtable

Now and then when using GCC I get cryptic errors like this:

undefined reference to 'vtable for classname'

When it's not caused by a missing library, this not-very-descriptive error message always causes me to dig through code files line by line to find the missing implementation for a virtual function.  Is there a way to make the linker tell me *which* virtual function it is missing, perhaps a flag or something?  Or is it maybe telling me but I don't understand what it's saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [gcc faq](http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#vtables):

> **When building C++, the linker says my
>   constructors, destructors or virtual
>   tables are undefined, but I defined
>   them**
>
> The ISO C++ Standard specifies that
>   all virtual methods of a class that
>   are not pure-virtual must be defined,
>   but does not require any diagnostic
>   for violations of this rule
>   [class.virtual]/8. Based on this
>   assumption, GCC will only emit the
>   implicitly defined constructors, the
>   assignment operator, the destructor
>   and the virtual table of a class in
>   the translation unit that defines its
>   first such non-inline method.
>
> Therefore, if you fail to define this
>   particular method, the linker may
>   complain about the lack of definitions
>   for apparently unrelated symbols.
>   **Unfortunately, in order to improve
>   this error message, it might be
>   necessary to change the linker, and
>   this can't always be done.**
>
> **The solution is to ensure that all
>   virtual methods that are not pure are
>   defined. Note that a destructor must
>   be defined even if it is declared
>   pure-virtual [class.dtor]/7.**

The solution that I adopt is search the classname and seek virtual methods declaration and check if there is any definition. I didn't found any other solution for this.